# Negascout with moves

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, implementation

I want to implement the NegaScout algorithm for the game "Chain Reaction". The game is implemented with a matrix of N rows and M columns, and a move is a pair (i,j). 
The pseudocode of Negascout is:

```
function pvs(node, depth, α, β, color)
if node is a terminal node or depth = 0
    return color × the heuristic value of node
for each child of node
    if child is first child
        score := -pvs(child, depth-1, -β, -α, -color)
    else
        score := -pvs(child, depth-1, -α-1, -α, -color)       (* search with a null window *)
        if α < score < β                                      (* if it failed high,
            score := -pvs(child, depth-1, -β, -score, -color)        do a full re-search *)
    α := max(α, score)
    if α ≥ β
        break                                            (* beta cut-off *)
return α
```

Now, i want the method to return not only the value "a", but also the row "i" and the column "j".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the order of your nodes does not change (no random shuffle),
you can expand the function pvs to also return the best node index:

```
function pvs(node, depth, α, β, color)
if node is a terminal node or depth = 0
    return color × the heuristic value of node, 0
for each child_index, child of enumerate(node): (*cycle over nodes and their indices*)
    if child is first child
        score, _ := pvs(child, depth-1, -β, -α, -color)
        score *= -1
    else
        score, _ := pvs(child, depth-1, -α-1, -α, -color)       (* search with a null window *)
        score *= -1
        if α < score < β                                      (* if it failed high,
            score, _ := pvs(child, depth-1, -β, -score, -color)        do a full re-search *)
            score *= -1
    α := max(α, score)
    if α ≥ β
        break                                            (* beta cut-off *)
return α, node_index
```

With the node_index you can find the best child_node from the root of your tree.
You can also choose to return the whole child_node with every call to pvs.
You should be able to get row and column from the child_node.